# cant write in the input when i add the value attibute

Tags: html, reactjs, laravel, input, vite

so i have my react project created by vite in this project i have the signup.jsx componnent where ther is an input but when i add the value onchange attributes i can no more write in the input here is my componnent

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { AiOutlineCaretLeft } from "react-icons/ai";
import Typed from "typed.js";
import axios from "axios";
import "./Css/Form.css";

const UserSignUP = () => {
        const el = useRef(null);
        const [typedInstance, setTypedInstance] = useState(null);

        useEffect(() => {
            const typed = new Typed(el.current, {
                strings: ["Employee", " "],
                typeSpeed: 50,
                loop: true,
                backDelay: 1000,
            });

            setTypedInstance(typed);

            return () => {
                typed.destroy();
            };
        }, []);

    // Post to Database
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        name: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
    });

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setFormData((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            [name]: value,
        }));
    };

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios
            .post("/api/signUp", formData)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };

    return (
        <div className="sm:w-[50vw] h-[88vh] bg-[#FF6600] flex flex-col">
            <div className="absolute flex self-end top-[50%] text-8xl text-[#1D1F21] animate-bounce">
                <AiOutlineCaretLeft />
            </div>
            <div className="flex justify-center">
                <h2 className="text-white text-3xl py-6 font-semibold">
                    I'm an <span className="text-red-600" ref={el} />
                </h2>
            </div>

            <div className="flex justify-center items-center">
                <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <div className="form_front w-full">
                        <div className="form_details text-white ">Sign Up</div>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            className="input"
                            placeholder="Full name"
                            value={formData.name}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            className="input"
                            placeholder="Email"
                            value={formData.email}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <input
                            type="password"
                            className="input"
                            placeholder="Password"
                            value={formData.password}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <button className="btn" type="submit">
                            Sign up
                        </button>
                        <span className="switch text-gray-500">
                            Already have an account?{" "}
                            <a href="/login" className="signup_tog text-white">
                                Login
                            </a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default UserSignUP;
```

i want to get the data from the  sign up form im my react component but whent i add the value attribute to the inputs i can no mote write in the input

Answer (score -1):

When you provide the value attribute, the input becomes a "controlled component," meaning its value is controlled by React state. As a result, any changes to the input will only reflect the state's value, not the actual typed characters.

To fix this, you should separate the value and onChange attributes properly for each input element. You can pass the value from the state to the input and use the onChange event to update the state when the user types.

Here is your updated code:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { AiOutlineCaretLeft } from "react-icons/ai";
import Typed from "typed.js";
import axios from "axios";
import "./Css/Form.css";

const UserSignUP = () => {
    const el = useRef(null);
    const [typedInstance, setTypedInstance] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const typed = new Typed(el.current, {
            strings: ["Employee", " "],
            typeSpeed: 50,
            loop: true,
            backDelay: 1000,
        });

        setTypedInstance(typed);

        return () => {
            typed.destroy();
        };
    }, []);

    // Post to Database
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        name: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
    });

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setFormData((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            [name]: value,
        }));
    };

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios
            .post("/api/signUp", formData)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };

    return (
        <div className="sm:w-[50vw] h-[88vh] bg-[#FF6600] flex flex-col">
            <div className="absolute flex self-end top-[50%] text-8xl text-[#1D1F21] animate-bounce">
                <AiOutlineCaretLeft />
            </div>
            <div className="flex justify-center">
                <h2 className="text-white text-3xl py-6 font-semibold">
                    I'm an <span className="text-red-600" ref={el} />
                </h2>
            </div>

            <div className="flex justify-center items-center">
                <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <div className="form_front w-full">
                        <div className="form_details text-white ">Sign Up</div>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            className="input"
                            placeholder="Full name"
                            name="name"
                            value={formData.name}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            className="input"
                            placeholder="Email"
                            name="email"
                            value={formData.email}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <input
                            type="password"
                            className="input"
                            placeholder="Password"
                            name="password"
                            value={formData.password}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <button className="btn" type="submit">
                            Sign up
                        </button>
                        <span className="switch text-gray-500">
                            Already have an account?{" "}
                            <a href="/login" className="signup_tog text-white">
                                Login
                            </a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default UserSignUP;
```